# Differentiating norm containing vectors and a matrix

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

I would like to differentiate

$$D = ||L^{-1} (x-y)||_2^{2}$$, while x and y are vectors and L is a matrix

Can someone show me how to do this? In other words, how to calculate:

$$\frac{dD}{dx}$$

Thank you for any help =)

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote $A:=L^{-1}$, then you can rewrite $D$ as $D=(x-y)^T.A^TA.(x-y)$, or in components

$$D=\sum_{i,j} (x-y)_i (A^TA)_{i,j} (x-y)_j$$

Now, since $A^TA$ is symmetric, $\partial D/\partial x_l$ yields:

$$ \frac{\partial D}{\partial x_l}=2\sum_{j} (A^TA)_{l,j}(x-y)_j $$

Comment: It makes sense but How to write it in matrix form, removing the $$\sum$$. No offense but I feel scared when I see such notation.

Comment: well, then it would be just $2(A^TA).(x-y)$ with $A=L^{-1}$.

Comment: When i was doing it manually I came to the result $$2A. (x-y). A$$, But when i used cookbook the result came out to be $$ (A^TA + (A^TA)^T)(x-y)$$. As $$A^TA$$ is symmetric I get the same result $$2A^TA(x-y)$$